# How to use order by clause in linq query with dynamic conditions?

Tags: c#, linq

I need a Linq query which joins multiple tables and need to use order by clause having conditions dynamically, that gets from a post request parameter.The parameter will be a string value and need to be appended inside `orderby` condition like `orderBy(item.+conditon+)`

```
 var x = db
   .table1
   .Join(db.table2,
         t1 => t1.id,
         t2 => t2.t2id,
         (t1,t2) => new{t1, t2})
   .Join(db.table3
         .....
   .Select(item => new {
       demo = item.t1.name
    })
   .OrderBy(item => item.+conditon+)
```

Comment: You need to look at expression trees: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/

Comment: You could check [Dynamic-Expressions](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are a limited number of possible fields to order by (maybe determined by the presence of indexes in the database) you may want to make a switch case to determine the `OrderBy` argument, but you could also create it using a dynamic expression builder, like this:

```
public static void Execute(string[] args)
{
    var set = new[] { new { a = "a", b = 2 }, new { a = "b", b = 1 } };
    var orderby = GetOrderBy(set, "b");
    var orderedSet = set.OrderByDescending(orderby).ToList();
}

private static Func<T, object> GetOrderBy<T>(IEnumerable<T> set, string key)
{
    var sourceType = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var property = typeof(T).GetProperty(key) ?? throw new KeyNotFoundException($"Property {key} not found.");

    var body = Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(sourceType, property), typeof(object));

    var expression = Expression.Lambda(body, sourceType);

    return (Func<T, object>)expression.Compile();
}
```

I'm not sure if you need a `Func<,>` or an `Expression<Func<,>>` for the `OrderBy`, but if you need the latter you only need to remove the Compile and change the return type.